# Color grid cells on map by column ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I have a map of grid cells containing information in each cell, such as name, description, task_order, and task_color.  I would like to be able to color each grid cell (polygon) by the task_color column in the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. However, I keep getting errors that tell me the object "task_color" is not found.

Here is a small portion of the polygon data:

```
library(ggplot2); library(raster); library(sp); library(rgdal)
{grid <- new("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", data = structure(list(Name = c("Z-11", 
"Z-12", "Z-13"), Description = c("", "", ""), task_order = c("2024, 2025", 
"2022", "2024, 2025"), task_color = c("grey", "orange", "grey"
)), row.names = 0:2, class = "data.frame"), polygons = list(new("Polygons", 
Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(-11246783.3082723, 
5732743.96617697), area = 2664202223.52297, hole = FALSE, 
    ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(-11271701.8610204, 
    -11219929.9538873, -11222013.1407718, -11273488.2206958, 
    -11271701.8610204, 5759458.56712098, 5757515.77249501, 
    5705991.0437186, 5707911.42465222, 5759458.56712098), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(-11246783.3082723, 
5732743.96617697), ID = "0", area = 2664202223.52297), new("Polygons", 
Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(-11248707.026411, 
5681356.48895818), area = 2633637487.98296, hole = FALSE, 
    ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(-11273488.2206958, 
    -11222013.1407718, -11224072.5484541, -11275254.1806112, 
    -11273488.2206958, 5707911.42465222, 5705991.0437186, 
    5654763.54855624, 5656662.02163351, 5707911.42465222), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(-11248707.026411, 5681356.48895818
), ID = "1", area = 2633637487.98296), new("Polygons", Polygons = list(
new("Polygon", labpt = c(-11250608.843431, 5630263.18907972
), area = 2603760110.49517, hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, coords = 
structure(c(-11275254.1806112, 
-11224072.5484541, -11226108.5815163, -11277000.0880492, 
-11275254.1806112, 5656662.02163351, 5654763.54855624, 5603826.6631605, 
5605703.71944054, 5656662.02163351), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), 
plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(-11250608.843431, 5630263.18907972
), ID = "2", area = 2603760110.49517)), plotOrder = 1:3, 
bbox = structure(c(-11277000.0880492, 5603826.6631605, -11219929.9538873, 
5759458.56712098), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", 
"y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 
+y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"))}
```

Here is my ggplot code:

```
 ggplot() +
 geom_path(grid, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), size = 2.5, alpha = 0.30, col = 'pink') + geom_polygon(data = grid, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), alpha = 0.30, fill = task_color)
```

How do I get each grid cell filled with the color in the task_color color column?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, OP.  Can you provide enough information for someone to recreate your problem to help you out?  The code you posted is not able to generate the object for me - I'm assuming you just have libraries `sp` and `ggplot2` loaded?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have the ggplot2, raster, sp, and rgdal libraries loaded.

Comment: Well, I guess dput doesn't work for polygons, so my code doesn't work.  I'll close the question.  All I'm really wondering is why the call to ggplot doesn't seem to recognize the task_color column.  It doesn't know it's there.

Comment: Without having your dataset available, I can only guess.  It seems you're planning to adjust `fill` to the color `task_color` - this is a column in your data that changes depending on the observation, right?  That needs to be inside `aes(..)`.  I'm assuming the data in `task_color` are color names, so you can then add `scale_fill_identity()` to indicate that the name of the color is actually in the column.  I think that would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

OP.  I cannot seem to load your data frame (good that you tried, but perhaps a bit difficult with polygon information), but perhaps the issue is related to referencing to apply the `fill=` outside of `aes()` via `fill=task_color`.

Since `task_color` is a column in your dataset, the value depends on the particular observation in your dataset.  In other words, the value of `task_color` should be *mapped* to the plot, which you need to do using `aes(...)`.  For this reason, you need to put `fill=task_color` inside `aes()`.

Once you do that, the colors should map correctly, but the colors will be wrong if you used values like `"green"`, `"blue"`, etc in the `task_color` column.  If you want to *use* the colors as they are indicated in this column, you do that with `scale_fill_identity()`.  You'll have to specify the type of legend via `guide=` if you want to keep the legend, and possibly also specify the `breaks=` and `labels=`, depending on what you're looking for in the legend.

Here's a full example.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  y=rnorm(10),
  mycolors=sample(c('Red','Blue', 'Green'), 10, replace=TRUE)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=5, fill=mycolors)
```

This gives an error: `object 'mycolors' not found`.  Since `mycolors` is a column, we need to reference it inside of `aes()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=5, aes(fill=mycolors))
```

[image]

You see that the *mapping* is correct, but the actual colors chosen are not.  To change the color of the fill for something already mapped, we'll need a `scale_` function, which in this case is `scale_fill_identity()`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point(shape=21, size=5, aes(fill=mycolors)) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide='legend')
```

[image]

Now they are mapped correctly.  You may find that you need something similar.  In your case, try this:

```
# I combined a bunch of the redundant references to data and
# your mapping into the initial call to ggplot()

ggplot(data=grid, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_path(size = 2.5, alpha = 0.30, col = 'pink') +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = task_colorx), alpha = 0.30) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide="legend")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!  I copied and tried your df example, but I'm getting the same error, that "object 'mycolors' not found".  Putting "fill  = task_colors" inside an aes is not working, either, with the same not found error.  Not sure what's going on here.  I'm wondering if something about my polygonsdataframe is not correct.